# Magento 2 how to make order comments as required field

Tags: checkout, orders, payment, magento-2.1.7

How to make order comments as required field and need to move before payment option?

Comment: What is the order comment extension you are using?

Comment: Thanks for comment MR.Sukumar 
Still not yet selected module if you suggest any module as per my requirement its helful

Comment: You can check my answer.

Comment: definitely recommend this module -: https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento2-delivery-instructions-and-date.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this order comment module:

https://github.com/boldcommerce/magento2-ordercomments

It works fine for me. You need to adjust the css according to your requirement. This module also inserts the order comment form just after the payment option and before **Place Order** button.

Comment: Ok thanks is there any posibility to change to radio buttos insted of text field like weight and height option

Comment: Only 2 options instead of text field?

Comment: yes two radio buttons values are width and height  if any one select width these shoud save . please help me out on this thanks in advance...

Comment: I ll check and let you know. As need to work on the existing extension with knockout.

Comment: Please help me out on this thanks in advance ...
my requirement is i need to add radio button option select customer either weight or length these shoud store in admin either payment page or shipping page .

Comment: Actually iam using this but it having textarea i need radio butiion please help me on this https://marketplace.magento.com/infobeans-magento2-oscomments.html

Comment: This is a bit more difficult than the suggested one.

Comment: Pls help me out on this I think shared link having requirements but need to change text area to radio buttons i was trying from 2days iam not able to do .pls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81144/discussion-between-chala-chalapathi-and-sukumar-gorai).